# VLOOKUP not returning right value - no error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two worksheets inside of a workbook which I use to formulate a report for management.

A part of this report includes an override function in-case the source data is wrong / inaccurate, this allows us to override the data with the correct values.

I use vlookups to check if a resource name is found in the override tab, if it is, return the override value.  This is working except for two cells where it is returning 0%.  There is no change in the formula across the sheet, other cells are working except for this one cell and i'm totally stumped as to what the problem could be.

Formula used to determine override value

> =IF($A2="","",IF($B2<=C$1,0%,1))  (Where C$1 is the date in the header)

Formula used in main sheet to pick override

> =IF($A2 = "","",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,'Manual Override'!$A:F,6,FALSE)),SUMIF('Config Pivots'!$D:$D,$A2,'Config Pivots'!BV:BV),VLOOKUP($A2,'Manual Override'!$A:F,6,FALSE)))

The issue seems to be in the following line

> VLOOKUP($A2,'Manual Override'!$A:F,6,FALSE) <-- this returns 0 rather than 100% but only for the one cell.

Sample data below

```
                         Override Sheet
 A           B              C           D          E           F
Name       End Date     February 2015   March 2015  April 2015  May 2015    June 2015
Joe        June 2015       100%           100%        100%       100%        100%



                    Main Sheet - What it should look like
 A           B              C               D          E           F           G
Name     Override?       February 2015  March 2015  April 2015  May 2015    June 2015
Joe         Yes           100%           100%        100%       100%        100%


                     Main Sheet - What it actually looks like
 A           B              C               D          E           F           G
Name     Override?       February 2015  March 2015  April 2015  May 2015    June 2015
Joe         Yes           100%           100%        100%         100%          0%
```

Comment: I only  need to lock the $A, its so I can drag the formula.  Its nothing to do with the locks as the formula is an exact duplicate of a working formula

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer, we had a duplicate entry in the Override sheet.  The formula was technically operating correctly, this was a human error